# JavaScript Iniciante - Problemas com retorno de informação

Tags: javascript

Porque esse código não está devolvendo a resposta certa?
Estou testando pelo console do Chrome. Nos testes eu troco o valor da var, mas nada acontece.

Seguindo o exemplo da aula que estou fazendo, está tudo correto. Estou esquecendo de algum detalhe?

Segue o código:

```js
var kills = 2;

  if (kills = 0){
   console.log('Seu noob!');
  
  }else if (kills > 1 && kills <= 3){
   console.log('Killer!');
  
  }else if (kills > 4 && kills <= 10) {
   console.log('Violent!');
  
  }else if (kills > 11){
   console.log('Unstoppable!');
  };
```

Comment: `if (kills = 0){` você esta fazendo uma atribuição e não uma comparação `==`

Comment: Maravilha! Era isso!
Resolvido!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tá atribuindo um valor (`kills = 0`) dentro de um `if` (condição).

Se você quer comparar valores, utilize o `==`:

```
if (kills == 0){}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso!
Resolvido!